# Disable Zod for Specific Objects or Allow Arbitrary Values for Specific Objects?

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, zod, trpc.io

I have a very large JS object I want to pass to trpc, through zod.

Right now I just want to play around with the object a bit, before creating my zod schema.

Is there a way to allow anything to be passed into zod (at least just in dev mode)? Or to just disable zod for the time being?

```js
  z.object({
        id: z.string(),
        data: z.object( // here i want to tell zod to allow any values)
      })
```

I know this is not the idea of zod at all, but would love to not have to build this crazy large schema right now only to throw it away later, because it's not really a finished/working thing right now.

Comment: `z.any()` - It's in the readme

Comment: You can also use `passthrough`

Comment: `z.any()` doesn't work if you pass the type as `z.ZodType<FooType>`, it will say property is optional if you used `z.any()` it seems. Had to do `z.object({}).passthrough()`.